# Postgresql inserting decimals values

Tags: sql, postgresql

please help how i can insert this value in this format on postgresql 45.000.00
i already config  one colum numeric 10 length and 2 precision but only saves values > 999.99

Comment: Please read [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Numbers are stored **without** any "format". You just insert them as a valid SQL number constant.

If you want to have a specific format you apply that when *displaying* the values:

```
create table jorge (n numeric(10,2));
insert into jorge values (4500000);
```

In SQL a decimal value may only contain a single `.` do mark the decimals. e.g. `3.14` or `123.42`

`45.000.00` is an **invalid** constant for a decimal in SQL (you will get a syntax error on the second dot:

```
postgres=> select 45.000.00;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ".00"
LINE 1: select 45.000.00;
                     ^
postgres=>
```

To display it the way you want, use [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html)

```
select to_char(n, '00G000G00')
from jorge;
```

Now the group separator used depends on your `lc_numeric` setting:

```
postgres=> set lc_numeric TO 'en';
SET
postgres=> select to_char(n, '00G000G00')
postgres-> from jorge;
  to_char
------------
  45,000,00
(1 row)


postgres=> set lc_numeric TO 'de';
SET
postgres=> select to_char(n, '00G000G00')
postgres-> from jorge;
  to_char
------------
  45.000.00
(1 row)
```

---

But it's **much** better to do this kind of formatting in the application, not in the SQL queries.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the values are provided as strings in this format and he doesn't know how to insert those?

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is to convert input strings like `'45.000.00'` to `numeric(10,2)`, a solution would be to use regular expressions:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('45.000.00', '\.(?=[^.]{3})', '', 'g')::numeric(10,2);
┌────────────────┐
│ regexp_replace │
├────────────────┤
│       45000.00 │
└────────────────┘
(1 row)
```